# JQuery input type checkbox prop("checked", false/true) does the opposite

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have an HTML checkbox element, with a Label element linked to it by the "for" attribute of Label, I tried to check/uncheck the checkbox element by capturing the click event of the Label element, 
Can somebody tell why this code does the opposite of what is intended,

```js
$("label").click(function() {

  $(this).toggleClass("active");

  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {

    $("#checker").prop("checked", true);
    console.log("checked");
    
  } 
  
  else {
    
    $("#checker").prop("checked", false);
    console.log("unchecked");

  }

});
```

```css
.active {
  background: green;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for='checker'>Check it</label>
<input type='checkbox' id='checker'>
```

Whereas this code works just fine.

```js
$("label").click(function(){
  
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  
  if($(this).hasClass("active")){
  
   setTimeout(function(){
    $("#checker").prop("checked",true);
   },0);
   console.log("checked");
      
  }
     
  else{

   setTimeout(function(){
    $("#checker").prop("checked",false);
   },0);
      console.log("unchecked");
   
  }
   
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: green;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for='checker'>Check it</label>
<input type='checkbox' id='checker'>
```

Comment: Clicking on the `label` for a checkbox does the same thing as clicking on the checkbox itself - it toggles the `checked` state. If you want to know what the current state of the element is, just look at `prop("checked")`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Yes I understand that clicking the Label element is equivalent to clicking the checkbox itself, In the above case the checkbox is unchecked by default (no active class on the Label), so when I click the label for the first time it should check the checkbox, another thing is I'm not asking the checkbox to invert its current state, I'm simply setting its state by testing the existence of active class on label.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the click to a `label` element that is linked to an `input`, here your `input`'s type is `checkbox`, changes the *checked state* of that checkbox.

You'll need to prevent that behaviour, simply by calling the [`.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) mehtod of the Event argument passed to the handler.

Here's a demo:

```js
// we're passing the Event to the handler, notice the argument 'e'.
$("label").click(function(e) {
  // disable the default behaviour of the click.
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {

    $("#checker").prop("checked", true);
    console.log("checked");
    
  } 
  
  else {
            $("#checker").prop("checked", false);
    console.log("unchecked");

  }

});
```

```css
.active {
  background: green;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for='checker'>Check it</label>
<input type='checkbox' id='checker'>
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: Thank for the response, can you please tell why the second part works ( with setTimeout)

Comment: @KaleemUllah that behaviour has a relation with the  `change` event for the `input`, it is visually unchecked you didn't explicitly change the checked attribute of the `input` by clicking the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue, solution to my problem was to do something like:

```
$(document).on('click', "label", function(event) {
  $("#checker").prop('checked', event.target.checked);
}).unbind('click', "label");
```